# Is it possible to detect when the screen turns on by the user (Android)?

Tags: android, android-screen, android-wake-lock

I found [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7068036/android-detect-general-use-by-user) from two year ago that somebody said that it can't be done.
I also found that I can use ACTION_USER_PRESENT to detect when a user unlock the screen, but can I detect when the user turns on the screen (by any action)?

EDIT: I want to know when the user press any button or do anything else that can turn on the screen

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/a/9478013/362298

Comment: This action used to detect when the screen goes on\off I want to know when the user turn on the screen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I started writing this as a comment but it turned out too big.

I couldn't find anything either. You [can't have a key listener on services](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3454710/onkeydown-in-a-service-global-hot-keys/3455094#3455094) and you apparently can't register a broadcast receiver for the power button, [only for media buttons](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/AudioManager.html#registerMediaButtonEventReceiver%28android.app.PendingIntent%29). Maybe you can do this on the broadcast receiver for the screen on and check which is the current activity)? [Like this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18115551/362298), for example:

```
ActivityManager am = (ActivityManager) this .getSystemService(ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
List<RunningTaskInfo> taskInfo = am.getRunningTasks(1);
ComponentName componentInfo = taskInfo.get(0).topActivity;
Log.d(WebServiceHelper.TAG, "CURRENT Activity ::" + taskInfo.get(0).topActivity.getClassName()+"   Package Name :  "+ componentInfo.getPackageName());
```

If you can get detect that the activity with the focus is the lockscreen, you increase the chances of being the user who turned on his/her phone. Maybe an alternative method on the broadcast receiver is [to detect if the phone is locked](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11623910/362298) but I guess this will be usually the case no matter the current activity being displayed:

```
KeyguardManager km = (KeyguardManager) getSystemService(Context.KEYGUARD_SERVICE);
boolean locked = km.inKeyguardRestrictedInputMode();
```

Hope this can help somehow. It's an interesting question.

Answer (score 6):

The system will broadcast [Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_ON](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_SCREEN_ON) which you can use to catch the event when the screen turns on.

```
public class MyReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        if (intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_ON)) {
            // your code here

        }
    }
}
```

Note that you can't broadcast this event yourself.

Comment: this is not what I asked for

Answer (score -1):

Are you looking for this?

```
@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged (Configuration newConfig)
```

and put this in your manifest for each activity that you want orientation notification:

```
android:configChanges="orientation" >
```

Comment: I don't want orientation change. I want to know when the user press any button or do anything else that can turn on the screen